# How are Apple II address lines mapped to DRAM rows and columns?

Tags: apple-ii, dram

The Apple II's MK4096 (4 Kbit) and [MK4116](https://archive.org/details/dram-f4116/mode/1up?view=theater) (16 Kbit) DRAM chips have
6 and 7 (respectively) address line inputs that are multiplexed: first the
row address bits and then the column address bits are passed to the chip.

The row address signals `R0-R6` (as I'll call them) may have an arbitrary
relationship to the `A0-A16` signals of the CPU address bus, i.e., there is
no strict need for `R6` to be `A13`, `A6`, `A0`, or any other particular
bit, and the mappings may be picked for the convenience of other parts of
the system, such as the [refresh logic](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/22207/7208) or the video generator
(though I'm not asking the reasons for doing that here).

So, on the Apple II, which of the CPU address bus signals `A0-A15` are
mapped to the DRAM row address signals `R0-R6`?

Answer (score 1):

The Apple II 4116 DRAM `RA0…RA6` row mapping is `A7 A2 A0 A8 A3 A1 A12`.

This is shown in a table in [Figure 5.3](https://archive.org/stream/Understanding_the_Apple_II_1983_Quality_Software#page/n260/mode/1up) on page 5-6 of *Understanding
the Apple II* by Jim Sather.

[image: Figure 5-3 excerpt]

This can be confirmed from the schematic in [Figure 22-3](https://archive.org/details/Apple_II_Reference_Manual_1979_Apple/page/n122/mode/1up?view=theater) on p.112 of
the *Apple II Reference Manual,* which I have reproduced with annotations
below.

[image: Apple II DRAM row-column decoding annotated]

The DRAM address line signals `RA0…RA5` enter from the right edge and are
routed to three 74LS153 selectors at E11, E12 and E13. The last DRAM
address line is labeled `E1,I2` (annotated as `(RA6)`) and runs to a memory
configuration block that, for a 16 Kbit DRAM (4116), routes it to half of a
74LS153 at C1.

The selectors switch between four inputs controlled by the `ϕ0` and `AX`
signals. For the selectors at E11/E12/E13, `ϕ0` at the S0 control input is
high for CPU DRAM access, letting `AX` (on S1 control input) switch between
inputs 1a/1b and 3a/3b. (0a/0b and 2a/2b are address inputs from the video
scanner.) The selector at C1 is wired slightly differently, with the S0 and
S1 control inputs reversed from the other two, but has the CPU address line
inputs changed to 2a/2b and 3a/3b to match.

`AX` is high for row select and low for column select. (I have not traced
this through the clock circuitry, as it's rather complex; I'm just taking
Sather's word for this one.) Thus when it's the CPU's turn to access RAM
(`ϕ0` high) and the row address is being generated (`AX` high), both
selector control inputs will be high and the 3a/3b address inputs will be
selected on all. Tracing these back to the address line designations on the
top and bottom edges of the schematic gives address lines `A7 A2 A0 A8 A3 A1 A12`, the same as Sather's diagram.